# Roslaunch utilising Gazebo 1.0 not Gazebo 1.3

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.0

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi All

I've installed Gazebo 1.3 to replace the Gazebo 1.0 as suggested [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/761/how-do-i-update-from-the-fuerte-gazebo-release-to/).

However when I go to run previous roslaunch files (for a gazebo 1.0 model) instead of launching Gazebo 1.3 and parsing the model to 1.3, it instead launches Gazebo 1.0 with no changes to what I had before installing Gazebo 1.3. I've followed the directions given, and my launch file is based on the old rosplugin.launch. However it doesn't seem to specify a version:

```
<launch>
  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find HMMv2)/worlds/HMMv2withGripper.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node name="imageviewhead" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" args="image:=/gazebo/cam_sensor1" />
  <node name="imageviewRH" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" args="image:=/gazebo/cam_sensor2" />
</launch>
```

now I take from the above launch file that it is using the simulator from the gazebo package in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator-gazebo/gazebo.

How do i change it to direct to where the gazebo 1.3 files are stored, the binaries are located in usr/bin, with the rest of the parts spread across the /usr/ folders

Cheers

Peter

I can run Gazebo 1.3 from the commandline no problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/964/roslaunch-utilising-gazebo-1.0-not-gazebo-1.3/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the problem is that `roslaunch` uses `rospack` to find the location of Gazebo. If the path to Gazebo 1.0 is first in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable, then roslaunch will use the 1.0 version.

Right now, the easiest way is to `sudo apt-get install drcsim`, and source the `/usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh` file.

**Update**

I think `roslaunch` can't launch programs that live outside of ROS. Someone should correct me if I'm wrong. One work around is to create a bash script that lives inside a ROS package. The bash script can then run gazebo. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
gazebo $1
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davide Zanin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/161/davide-zanin/) on 2013-01-28**:
Don't working for me

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-02-06**:
yeah sorry nate, but installing drcsim, copying across all the paths from the setup file to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, doesn't work either. is the drcsim formatted as a ros stack? or would removing the gazebo 1.0 stack be suitable (by moving the directory and replacing the executables in the fuerte bin folder with the 1.3 executables? )

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-02-19**:
What is DRC anyways?  I tried to google it, found the user guide, but the explanation of what it is is not implemented yet: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide .

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-02-20**:
I believe its the simulator for the Darpa Robotics Challenge. Theres a simulation track in the competition and the DRC is the simulator to use. Its based on Gazebo with the latest refinements

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-26**:
PMilani is correct. The simulation component is called the Virtual Robotics Challenge, which is taking place this June.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-02-26**:
Thanks.